# service to service auth using AAD across tenants

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I need to do service to service auth in multi-tenant environment, how do i do that?
Say I have service1 hosted as app service in tenant1 with app id1. And I have service2 hosted in tenant2 with app id2. I want service1 to access service2 using a AAD token and service2 has to validate this token to authorize. Any idea or reference would help.

Also these are backend apis and not a client application where user can consent.
I could do this in single tenant, by registering 2 apps and adding API permissions and using jwt token.
But i'm not sure how to do this across tenants.

Answer (score 0):

Even we have two different tenants with two different applications it is easily can be implemented . You can achieve it using [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) in Azure AD. Client credential flow does not require user involvement and it will automatically work with application permissions.